# Why isn't SetLayeredWindowAttributes() working on my WinUI 3 desktop overlay background?

Tags: winapi, overlay, transparency, winui-3, layered-windows

I'm trying to create a desktop overlay using WINUI 3 (Windows App SDK 1.3).

I'm trying to make the window background transparent, just like you can do in WinForms by using `TransparencyKey`. However, since as far as I know, WinUI 3 doesn't have such a convenient way to achieve that, I had to use `SetLayeredWindowAttributes`. However, the following code does not change the window transparency in any way:

```cs
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(_hWnd, 0, 128, LWA_COLORKEY);
```

However, globally changing the transparency works:

```cs
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(_hWnd, 0, 128, LWA_ALPHA);
```

Which is very confusing to me.

This is not exactly my whole code but it's the minimum you need to replicate the problem:

```cs
InitializeComponent();

_hWnd = WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);

var exStyle = (User32.SetWindowLongFlags)User32.GetWindowLong(_hWnd, User32.WindowLongIndexFlags.GWL_EXSTYLE);
exStyle |= User32.SetWindowLongFlags.WS_EX_LAYERED;
User32.SetWindowLong(_hWnd, User32.WindowLongIndexFlags.GWL_EXSTYLE, exStyle);

SetLayeredWindowAttributes(_hWnd, 0, 128, LWA_COLORKEY);
```

This is what I am getting:

[image: transparency not working]

I was expecting the black background to become transparent.

To sum up, this line of code is not working as expected: `SetLayeredWindowAttributes(_hWnd, 0, 128, LWA_COLORKEY)`

Comment: To be honest, I am surprised that LWA_ALPHA works at all.  WinUI uses the render of D3D, while SetLayeredWindowAttributes relies on GDI rendering.

Comment: Ah I see @Nick , do you know what I can do to achieve the same result with D3D? Or perhaps changing the app to use GDI instead would be better? If you could point me to the right direction I would appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: WinUI3 is based on Direct Composition, the "Visual Layer" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/composition/visual-layer), layered window are more a GDI thing. Of course you can use GDI instead of WinUI3. But if you want to continue with WinUI3, there's nothing builtin, only all sort of "hacks": https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/1247#issuecomment-1374474960 some not so far from what you're trying to do

Comment: Thank you @SimonMourier , I took a look at this repository (was in the issue you mentioned) and was able to make it work!
https://github.com/cnbluefire/WinUI3TransparentBackground

Comment: You should answer yourself if you're happy with a solution (avoid links, put some relevant code)

Comment: I use myself LWA_ALPHA. My article on that is [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5359576/WinUI3-in-Existing-Win32-Applications). My current problem is to how to make the Win32 window "bottom", that is, to allow the WinUI3 menu to be shown over it.